# Play youtube video from my application on Google Home

Tags: dialogflow-es, chromecast, google-home

Google home is connected to chromcast I have ability to play youtube video. But when I launch my application base on dialogflow, I don't know how to do it. 
Maybe I should use a different environment instead of dialogflow? There is any ability to have access to chromecast remotely (from external server)?

Thx

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to trigger a cast application from a Google Assistant Action without specifically partnering with Google.